# como pasar multiples parametros por url?

Tags: php, http

Quiero pasar dos variables a través de la misma url

Intenté esto:

```
$id = '24,54,32,65,34';
$agencia = 'AGIP, ARBA';

"url?id=$id&agencia=$agencia"
```

**Aclaración:** *si o si debe ser por parametro y variables*

Estoy usando curl y decode de esta forma:

```
function getVencimientos($id){
  $result = fetchVencimientos($id);
  $decode = json_decode(remove_utf8_bom($result), true)['data'];
  var_dump($decode);
  return $decode;
}

function fetchVencimientos($id){
  $agencia = 'AGIP, ARBA';
  $ch = curl_init("url?id=$id&agencia=$agencia");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
  ]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

Me devuelve un codigo html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que no intentas pasarlas como JSON?

```
$id = [24,54,32,65,34];
$agencia = [AGIP, ARBA];

"url?id=".json_encode($id)."&agencia=".json_encode($agencia);
```

y luego del otro lado obtienes el parametro GET y le haces un json_decode para recuperar el arreglo.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, ya que por comentarios no es muy entendible

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es concatenar las variables sacándolas del string como tal para que puedan obtener su valor. Hazlo de la siguiente forma:

```
"url?id=".$id."&agencia=".$agencia
```

Comment: ya lo intenté sin embargo me devuelve un `html`. Olvide decir que estoy usando curl_init.

Comment: Ámbas formas son válidas (como él lo pone y como tu lo señalas), incluso si sabes que un caracter dentro del string puede interferir con el nombre de tu variable de la que quieres obtener el valor, puedes envolverla entre llaves "{" "}" ($url="algo.php?var={$x}_{$y}"; por ejemplo) así como lo señalan aquí http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php